# Hive create aggregated results for offset range

Tags: sql, hadoop, join, hive

I have 2 tables like:

*TABLE_ONE* (Small table with 500 records)

```
+--------+----------+------------+
| E_CODE | V_NUMBER | DATE       |
+--------+----------+------------+
| E1     | 1        | 2016-01-08 |
| E2     | 1        | 2016-01-05 |
| E3     | 1        | 2016-01-06 |
| E4     | 1        | 2016-01-03 |
| E5     | 1        | 2016-01-09 |
+--------+----------+------------+
```

*TABLE_TWO* (Huge table with more then 100,000,000 records)

```
+----------+-----+
|DATE      |VALUE|
+----------+-----+
|2016-01-01|1    |
|2016-01-02|2    |
|2016-01-03|3    |
|2016-01-04|4    |
|2016-01-05|5    |
|2016-01-06|6    |
|2016-01-07|7    |
|2016-01-08|8    |
|2016-01-09|9    |
|2016-01-10|10   |
+----------+-----+
```

I want to generate result table which will have aggregated data for predecided range. Like (5 days before start date)

*RESULT TABLE*

```
+--------+----------+------------+-------+
| E_CODE | V_NUMBER | DATE       | VALUE |
+--------+----------+------------+-------+
| E1     | 1        | 2016-01-08 | 25    |
| E2     | 1        | 2016-01-05 | 6     |
| E3     | 1        | 2016-01-06 | 15    |
| E4     | 1        | 2016-01-03 | 3     |
| E5     | 1        | 2016-01-09 | 30    |
+--------+----------+------------+-------+
```

**Approach 1**
Create a range table from *TABLE_TWO* (something like)

*RANGE_TABLE*

```
+----------+----------+-----+
|START_DATE|END_DATE  |VALUE|
+----------+----------+-----+
|2016-01-01|2016-01-01|1    |
|2016-01-01|2016-01-02|3    |
|2016-01-01|2016-01-03|6    |
|2016-01-01|2016-01-04|10   |
|2016-01-01|2016-01-05|15   |
|2016-01-02|2016-01-06|20   |
|2016-01-03|2016-01-07|25   |
|2016-01-04|2016-01-08|30   |
|2016-01-05|2016-01-09|35   |
|2016-01-06|2016-01-10|40   |
|2016-01-07|2016-01-10|34   |
|2016-01-08|2016-01-10|27   |
|2016-01-09|2016-01-10|19   |
|2016-01-10|2016-01-10|10   |
+----------+----------+-----+
```

And then join it with *TABLE_ONE* on *t2_range.END_DATE = date_sub(t1.date, 1)*. I haven't found a way to create range table.

**Approach 2**
Do an inequality join and get the desired data:

```
select
    t1.e_code,
    t1.v_number,
    min(t1.date),
    sum(t2.value) as value
from
    table_one t1 join
    table_two t2 on true
where
    t2.date between 
        DATE_SUB(t1.date, 6) and 
        DATE_SUB(t1.date, 1)
group by
    t1.e_code,
    t1.v_number
```

As it is inequality join query, only 1 reducer is there and hence query is too slow. Even for small dataset it is taking ages to fetch the results.

**Question**: 
How can I solve this issue?

- If **approach 1**, then how to generate range_table.
- If **approach 2**, then how to get inequality join working efficiently.
- Any other better solution.